# Clojure map into vector

Tags: clojure

I have this collection of movies by directors:

```
([{:title "Blade Runner 2049", :genre "Action", :year 2017}
  {:title "Gladiator", :genre "Drama", :year 2000}
  {:title "Mars", :genre "Adventure", :year 2015}
  {:title "American Gangster", :genre "Crime", :year 2007}]
 [{:title "The Godfather", :genre "Crime", :year 1972}
  {:title "Apocalypse Now", :genre "Drama", :year 1979}
  {:title "Jack", :genre "Comedy", :year 1996}]
 [{:title "The Wolf", :genre "Comedy", :year 2013}
  {:title "GoodFellas", :genre "Crime", :year 1990}
  {:title "The Departed", :genre "Drama", :year 2006}
  {:title "The Aviator", :genre "Drama", :year 2004}])
```

which is a list of 3 vectors(Directors) and the corresponding movies

If I do:

```
(doseq [directors-movie movies]
   (doseq [movie directors-movie]
     (println movie)))
```

I can print all movies one by one:

```
#imdb.movie.Movie{:title Blade Runner 2049, :genre Action, :year 2017}
#imdb.movie.Movie{:title Gladiator, :genre Drama, :year 2000}
#imdb.movie.Movie{:title Mars, :genre Adventure, :year 2015}
#imdb.movie.Movie{:title American Gangster, :genre Crime, :year 2007}
#imdb.movie.Movie{:title The Godfather, :genre Crime, :year 1972}
#imdb.movie.Movie{:title Apocalypse Now, :genre Drama, :year 1979}
#imdb.movie.Movie{:title Jack, :genre Comedy, :year 1996}
#imdb.movie.Movie{:title The Wolf, :genre Comedy, :year 2013}
#imdb.movie.Movie{:title GoodFellas, :genre Crime, :year 1990}
#imdb.movie.Movie{:title The Departed, :genre Drama, :year 2006}
#imdb.movie.Movie{:title The Aviator, :genre Drama, :year 2004}
```

What I need is to put all this movies into a Vector.

Thanks,
R.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
(reduce into [] l)
```

or

```
(into [] cat l)
```

will do (where `l` is your input list)

Comment: (apply concat data) has less tokens )

Comment: (into [] cat l) has less tokens than (apply concat data) and produces a vector, like was asked for :-)

Answer (score 3):

This will do it:

```
(-> movies
    flatten
    vec)
```

Alternatives are:

```
(->> movies
     (apply concat)
     vec)
```

, and:

```
(->> movies
     (mapcat identity)
     vec)
```